# How to convert gregorian date to islamic date in php and store it in database?

Tags: php

I want to get synchronized Hijri and Gregorian  and store both in database in php.  How can it be done?

Comment: She wants to do it with php only, not with Javascript @RiggsFolly

Comment: I would suggest it would be simpler to maintain if you standardize on one calendar and then write/find a converter

Comment: Ok what if I have gregorian calendars dates. How can I convert them into Hijri dates?

Comment: Look for a class converting Gregorian to Hijiri dates. For example this one: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6848-PHP-Convert-dates-between-Gregorian-to-Hijri-calendars.html#information

Answer (score 4):

Use [HijriDateLib](https://github.com/hubaishan/HijriDateLib) to convert Hijri dates to Gregorian, store dates is database as unix timestamp (data type bigint).

First you must download and require the Hijri class

```
<?php
require_once('hirji.class.php');
```

To return current date with both Hijri and Gregorian use:

```
echo (new hijri\datetime())->format('D _j _M _Yهـ (j-m-Yم)');
```

to store Hijri date in database:

```
SQL="INSERT IN table1 (timestamp_colum) VALUES " . (hijri\datetime::createFromHijri(1441,9,17))->format('U');
```

to view stored date with both Hijri and Gregorian:

```
echo (new hijri\datetime($row->timestamp_column))->format('D _j _M _Yهـ (j-m-Yم)');
```